# SQL query for Matching Red and Green Flags

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

For a dating app a user has to set white flags which describe him/herself. He/she (I don't cover the gender in the example data) can then select a couple of green and red flags which have priorities and are used to find potential partners. Priorities are used to priorities white, green and red flags. Lower number means more important.

- A is a vegetarian and likes dogs but hates cats.
- B is a vegetarian and likes dogs.
- C is the same as B but likes dogs more than being a vegetarian.
- D is a vegetarian, likes dogs and likes cats.

Is there an SQL query which returns the best matches for A in a sorted way?

The wanted result: [B, C]

Is there a way to even fine tune that to use the green and red flags of B, C and D to optimise the result even better?

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/acywOnYi)

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE flags (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE userflags (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id integer REFERENCES users (id),
  color varchar(255),
  flag_id integer REFERENCES flags (id),
  priority integer
);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D');

INSERT INTO flags (name) VALUES 
('Vegetarian'),('Vegan'),('Dog owner'),('Cat owner');

INSERT INTO userflags (user_id, color, flag_id, priority) VALUES 
 (1,'white',1,1)
,(1,'white',3,2)
,(1,'green',1,1)
,(1,'green',3,2)
,(1,'red',  4,1)

,(2,'white',1,1)
,(2,'white',3,2)
,(2,'green',1,1)
,(2,'green',3,2)

,(3,'white',1,2)
,(3,'white',3,1)
,(3,'green',1,1)
,(3,'red',  3,1)

,(4,'white',1,1)
,(4,'white',3,2)
,(4,'white',4,3);
```

Comment: Show what results you want and explain why. Do you want exactly the top 2 matches? How do you define "top" in this context? Do you need both green and red to match or only one? Or even none, but prioritize the ones that match? What does it mean to have a priority on the white flags, does that override the priority on the corresponding green/red flag?

Comment: Having a table that holds rank values for flags would be a good start. `INSERT INTO flagfanks (flag, rank) VALUES ('red', 0), ('white',1), ('green', 2);` Then you can join two user's `userflags` records `flag_id` and do some math with `flagranks.rank` and `priority` to derive an index that you can sum up. Like `SUM((userA.rank - userB.rank) * priority) as match_index` (as a start). Then start tweaking that to match your expectations.